# Weakly symmetric rings and derived equivalences

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

A ring $R$ with Jacobson radical $J$ is called Frobenius in case $R/J \cong soc(R)$ as left and right $R$-modules and weakly symmetric in case we even have $R/J \cong soc(R)$ as $R$-bimodules.

> Question 1: Is there a classification of representation-finite Frobenius rings (up to some other classification such as division rings)?

In particular, what are the representation-finite local (or commutative) Frobenius rings? (I guess local implies weakly-symmetric?)

> Question 2: Is being weakly symmetric closed under derived equivalences?

(this is true for finite dimensional algebras)